# GIT: Problems Understanding Branch Naming Convention

Tags: git

I am having problem understanding the differences between 'master' 'origin master' 'origin/master', 'remotes/origin/master'!! Is there any rule for naming GIT branches? I suppose 'origin master' is the master branch in the repository while origin/master is my local reflection of the repository master branch, then what is remotes/origin/master?! Also, sometimes I have to use origin/master to refer to the repository master branch (I forget the case though, but I feel I have been into such thing before), why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read up on the [git branching model](http://progit.org/book/ch3-0.html) to understand this properly. However, following is a quick and dirty explanation.

Branches in git are pointers to certain nodes in the DAG tree of commits. They will move when you perform some operations (e.g. a commit). `master` is one such pointer which is by default the one created when you initialise a fresh repository. It's your "main branch" (so to speak).

Since git is a distributed version control system, there's a difference between your local repository and a remote one (like one on github). These are called `remote`s and when you clone for the first time, the remote from which you cloned is automatically created and named `origin` (i.e. where your code originated from).

When you say `<remote>/<branch>`, it's referring the location of the pointer `<branch>` not on your local clone but on the `<remote>`. So if, after cloning, you make 10 commits to your local branch, `master` (your local branch) will be 10 commits ahead of `origin/master`. To make it clear to git that we're talking about a remote, the convention `remotes/<remote_name>/<branch_name>` is used.

I think you need to read the book which I've linked to before you use git. It's a little non-intuitive for people coming from a version control system like `svn` or others. The branching model for git is a lot simpler than the ones for centralised systems.

Comment: "When you say <remote>/<branch>, it's referring the location of the pointer <branch> not on your local clone but on the <remote>." <-- I know what you mean, but I think this is phrased a misleadingly - <remote>/<branch> really is a ref in your local clone, and it doesn't necessarily match <branch> in the <remote> repository.  I think it's most helpful to think of <remote>/<branch> as a ref that caches the state of <branch> on <remote> from the last time you did a "git fetch", "git pull" or "git push" (if the push updated <branch> on <remote>)...